# Getting third View Controller to display crashes my app - Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, option-type

I have 4 view controllers: [image: Image of 4 controllers in folder tree], and the SwitchingViewController does all of my view switching between the different views. I have a Yellow View, a Blue view, and a Green View. The app already swaps between the yellow and the blue views fine, but when I try to swap to the green view it crashes with an error. `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`.

This is what the storyboard and app look like:

[image: Storyboard Image]
[image: iPhone Simulator of app]

The switch views button at the bottom left of the phone are what control the view switches, but again it only works for going from yellow to blue, then crashes from blue to green.

Here is my SwitchingViewController.swift and I believe that the problem might be with line 79, but I am unsure exactly.

```
class SwitchingViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
//        blueViewController =
//            storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Blue")
//            as! BlueViewController
//        blueViewController.view.frame = view.frame
//        switchViewController(from: nil, to: blueViewController)
        yellowViewController =
            storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Yellow")
            as! YellowViewController
        yellowViewController.view.frame = view.frame
        switchViewController(from: nil, to: yellowViewController)
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        
        if blueViewController != nil && blueViewController!.view.superview == nil {
            blueViewController = nil
        }
        if yellowViewController != nil && yellowViewController!.view.superview == nil {
            yellowViewController = nil
        }
        if greenViewController != nil && greenViewController!.view.superview == nil {
            greenViewController = nil
        }
    }
    
    private var blueViewController: BlueViewController!
    private var yellowViewController: YellowViewController!
    private var greenViewController: GreenViewController!
    
    @IBAction func switchViews(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if yellowViewController?.view.superview == nil {
            if yellowViewController == nil {
                yellowViewController =
                    storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Yellow")
                    as! YellowViewController
            }
        } else if blueViewController?.view.superview == nil {
            if blueViewController == nil {
                blueViewController =
                    storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Blue")
                    as! BlueViewController
            }
        } else if greenViewController?.view.superview == nil {
            if greenViewController == nil {
                greenViewController =
                    storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Green")
                    as! GreenViewController
            }
        }
        
        UIView.beginAnimations("View Flip", context: nil)
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.4)
        UIView.setAnimationCurve(.easeInOut)
        // Switch view controllers
        if yellowViewController != nil
                    && yellowViewController!.view.superview != nil {
            UIView.setAnimationTransition(.flipFromRight, for: view, cache: true)
            blueViewController.view.frame = view.frame
            switchViewController(from: yellowViewController, to: blueViewController)
        } else if blueViewController != nil
                    && blueViewController!.view.superview != nil {
            UIView.setAnimationTransition(.flipFromRight, for: view, cache: true)
            greenViewController.view.frame = view.frame
            switchViewController(from: blueViewController, to: greenViewController)
        } else {
            UIView.setAnimationTransition(.flipFromRight, for: view, cache: true)
            yellowViewController.view.frame = view.frame
            switchViewController(from: greenViewController, to: yellowViewController)
        }
        UIView.commitAnimations()
        
    }
    
    private func switchViewController(from fromVC:UIViewController?, to toVC:UIViewController?) {
        if fromVC != nil {
            fromVC!.willMove(toParent: nil)
            fromVC!.view.removeFromSuperview()
            fromVC!.removeFromParent()
        }
        
        if toVC != nil {
            self.addChild(toVC!)
            self.view.insertSubview(toVC!.view, at: 0)
            toVC!.didMove(toParent: self)
        }
    }

}
```

Finally, here is an image of the crash report:

[image: Crash Report Image]

Any help would be great to figure out why it crashes with that error, please let me know if additional information is necessary to understand better.

Comment: Have you correctly set the custom classes for each of your scenes?  You have force downcasts, so if the view controller class isn't correct you will get a crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is these lines:

```
private var blueViewController: BlueViewController!
private var yellowViewController: YellowViewController!
private var greenViewController: GreenViewController!
```

You have your variables `blueViewController`, `yellowViewController`, and `greenViewController` declared as "implicitly unwrapped optionals." (The `!` just after the type.)

That tells the compiler "Trust me. This variable is optional, but I am **absolutely certain** that it will never be nil by the time my code runs. I'm so sure that you should crash if I'm wrong."

Get rid of all of those exclamation points. I call both the "implicitly unwrapped optional" operator and the closely related force-unwrap operator "crash if nil" operators, because that's what they do.

Until you really, really understand optionals, you should avoid both of those like the plague. It's more work to unwrap your optionals every time you use them, but not doing it is likely to create crashes like this one.

Comment: Thank you! That explains a lot, and now it doesn't crash. I appreciate your response and explanation